# Установка PyBrain в Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Как установить PyBrain в Windows?

Comment: 1) идем в гугл  2) ищем How to install PyBrain on windows 3) Переходим по второй ссылке http://blog.habrador.com/2012/11/how-to-install-pybrain-on-windows.html 4)PROFIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот само руковотство: http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/installation.html
Но если в двух словах, то должен уже быть сам python, а потом с помощью, например, gitBash клонировать на свой компьютер файлы и запустить скрипт setup.py